# web.config 301 redirect url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, iis, web-config

My canonical urls were pointing to ://www.example.com/xyz/ (without http) and now google bots are hitting my servers with the below url

http://www.example.com/xyz/:/www.example.com/xyz/

I would like them to redirect back to http://www.example.com/xyz/

Answer (score 0):

htaccess solution

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/:([a-zA-Z0-9-./]+) /$1/$2/ [L]